# Ionic Worklight Page not displaying after HTTP request

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having an issue displaying the content in the page after the `Worklight http request` has been executed.

The weird thing is that when I go to another page and I come back, the content gets displayed. It's like if it needs to be refreshed or something. I can see the `console.log()` data was received, but page was not refreshed.

This is my code:

```
  $stateProvider.state('accounts', {
    url: "/accounts",
    templateUrl: 'views/accounts.html',
    controller: function($scope, $ionicScrollDelegate, $rootScope){

        var req = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/JavaMQ/bankmq/getAccounts/"+$rootScope.globalReqUserId, WLResourceRequest.GET);
            req.send().then(function(resp){
            var x2js = new X2JS();
            resp.responseText = x2js.xml_str2json(resp.responseText); //to JSON     
            $scope.reqUserId = resp.responseText['ASI_Message']['Riyad_Bank_Header']['Requestor_User_ID'];
            $scope.accountsList = resp.responseText['ASI_Message']['Repeating_Group_Section']['Repeating_Group'];
            console.log($rootScope);
        })  
    }
```

});

UPDATE:
I noticed that I also keep getting the following when I moved the project to Windows (Never happened in my mac)

```
Deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds
Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Worklight but the [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html) indicate that the `send().then()` handles both the `onSuccess` and `onFailure`.

Maybe the then() is expecting 2 parameters like this:

```
var request = WLResourceRequest(url, method, timeout);

request.send(content).then(

    function(response) {
   // success flow
 }, 

    function(error) {
   // fail flow
 } 

);
```

If that doesn't work, can you put a breakpoint at the start of `var x2js = new X2JS();` and tell us what happens?